# How can I cite something as "e.g. Author, 200X" with natbib in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, citations

Is it possible to cite something in Latex so that the end result is `(e.g. Author, 200X)`?
At the moment I use this:

```
(e.g. \citep{Author200X})
```

But I was wondering if there was a better strategy. I'm using TeXshop, and natbib.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `\citep[e.g.][]{Author200X}`

Have a look at http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php.